# mysql select subquery in yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

Hi i'd like to let this

```
ID | Forename | Surname | Created
---------------------------------
 1 | Tom      | Smith   | 2008-01-01
 1 | Tom      | Windsor | 2008-02-01
 2 | Anne     | Thorn   | 2008-01-05
 2 | Anne     | Baker   | 2008-03-01
 3 | Bill     | Sykes   | 2008-01-20
```

becomes like this

```
ID | Forename | Surname | Created
---------------------------------
 1 | Tom      | Windsor | 2008-02-01
 2 | Anne     | Baker   | 2008-03-01
 3 | Bill     | Sykes   | 2008-01-20
```

so I make a mysql query :

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM tableA as A 
WHERE created = (
    SELECT 
        MAX(created) 
    FROM tableA GROUP BY id having id=A.id
);
```

and it works in mysql as well , I can get what i want.

but i dont know how to write this in yii2 active

I have tried :

```
 $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
                        ->select(['A.*'])
                        ->from('tableA AS A')
                        ->where('created = (SELECT MAX(created) from tableA GROUP BY id having id=A.id');

$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
```

but it didn't work.

thanks.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to accomplish. Try to define it in words first and then will build the query for it. And this does not seem like an YII2 issue, just a regular mySql query.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry I think thats not the problem . cuz i can work with mysql query.   I got the other serial as my primary key

Comment: That's ALWAYS the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$subQuery = (new \yii\db\Query())
  ->select(['id', 'max_created' => 'MAX(created)'])
  ->from('tableA')
  ->groupBy('id'); 

$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
  ->select(['A.*'])
  ->from('tableA AS A')
  ->leftJoin(['B' => $subQuery], 'B.id = A.id')
  ->where('A.created = B.max_created');

$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
```

You can get details here: [Yii2 guide section for `Query->leftJoin`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#leftJoin()-detail)

And i found related topic here: 
[SELECT sub-query with WHERE condition in Yii2 find() / QueryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201458/select-sub-query-with-where-condition-in-yii2-find-querybuilder)

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, assuming a PK on (id,created), a better (i.e. more efficient) way to write that query would be:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id,MAX(created) created FROM my_table GROUP BY id ) y 
    ON y.created = x.created 
   AND y.id = x.id;
```